# VBA runtime error # 1004 does not display the entire file path

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA code:

```
        tableFilePath = "SomeTableFilePathName"
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="SomeTableName" & j, Formula:= _
      "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & tableFilePath & """),[Delimiter="","", Columns=15, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{""Column1"", Int64.Type}, {""Column2"", type number}, {""Column3"", type number}, {""Column4"", type number}" & _
      ", {""Column5"", type number}, {""Column6"", type number}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type number}, {""Column9"", type number}, {""Column10"", type number}, {""Column11"", type number}, {""Column12"", type text}, {""Column13"", type number}, {""Column14"", type number}, {""Column15"", Int64.Type}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
      "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=SomeTableName" & j & ";Extended Properties=""""" _
      , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
      .CommandType = xlCmdSql
      .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [SomeTableName]")
      .RowNumbers = False
      .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
      .PreserveFormatting = True
      .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
      .BackgroundQuery = True
      .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
      .SavePassword = False
      .SaveData = True
      .AdjustColumnWidth = True
      .RefreshPeriod = 0
      .PreserveColumnInfo = True
      .ListObject.DisplayName = "SomeTableName"
      .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Application.CommandBars("Queries and Connections").Visible = False
    ActiveSheet.Name = "SomeTableName"
```

If the "tableFilePath" is set to an incorrect path (i.e. the specified file name can't be found in that path), then I get the error 1004 message which, as expected, states that the specified file path can't be found.

However, part of the file path in the error message is cut off (e.g. instead of the error message showing the entire "SomeTableFilePathName", it only shows something like "SomeTableFi").

Is there some way, either in the VBA code itself or somewhere else, to fix this so the error message displays the entire file path that can't be found?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `Dir` function to validate the file path before creating a query.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dir function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008898)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
    tableFilePath = "SomeTableFilePathName"
    If Len(Dir(tableFilePath)) > 0 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="SomeTableName" & j, Formula:= _
        ' ... your code
        ActiveSheet.Name = "SomeTableName"
    Else
        MsgBox "Source file can't be found: " & vbCrLf & tableFilePath
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

With checking the Err value you can get this result:

```
Sub errdisp()

filenam = "book22.xlsm"
filepath = "C:\users\Very long directory name of a user\desktop\"
On Error Resume Next
Set aa = Workbooks.Open(filepath & filenam)
If Err = 1004 Then
 MsgBox "File not found:  " & filepath & filenam, vbCritical, "ERROR 1004"
End If
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing the query using VBA because the file path changes?
This may not be what you're looking for, but you could use a function within Power Query to pick up the file path from a cell on a sheet and then hard-code your query rather than create it each time.

Create a named range containing your path:
[image]

Create a query to pick up that file path.  I've called this **fGetNamedRange**:

```
let GetNamedRange=(NamedRange) => 
    let
        name = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=NamedRange]}[Content],
        value = name{0}[Column1]
    in
        value
in GetNamedRange
```

Create your original query, but changing where it picks the file up from - so changing this bit of your query `File.Contents(""" & tableFilePath & """`

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(Text.From(fGetNamedRange("MyFilePath"))),[Delimiter=",", Columns=15, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Column2", type number}, {"Column3", type number}, {"Column4", type number}, 
                                                         {"Column5", type number}, {"Column6", type number}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type number}, 
                                                         {"Column9", type number}, {"Column10", type number}, {"Column11", type number}, {"Column12", type text}, 
                                                         {"Column13", type number}, {"Column14", type number}, {"Column15", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Then a bit of VBA code to check the file path and refresh the query:

```
Sub Test()

    If Dir(Sheet1.Range("MyFilePath")) <> "" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Query1").Refresh
    Else
        MsgBox "File doesn't exist."
    End If

End Sub
```